# Machine specific PATCH application from different layer yocto

Tags: yocto, patch

I want to apply one patch which is machine specific(old-silicon) from my custom meta layer, for that I defined MACHINEOVERRIDES in my meta-dcu/conf/machine/old_silicon.conf

```
MACHINEOVERRIDES =. "old_silicon:"
```

Then I applied my patch in meta-dcu/recipes-rzg2l/recipes-bsp/trusted-firmware-a/trusted-firmware-a.bbappend

```
SRC_URI_old_silicon += "file://0002-trusted-firmware-a-add-rd-wr-64-bit-reg-workaround.patch"
```

But I am getting error:

ERROR: trusted-firmware-a-v2.6+git-r0 do_patch: Applying patch '0002-trusted-firmware-a-add-rd-wr-64-bit-reg-workaround.patch' on target directory '/build/tmp/work/old_silicon-poky-linux/trusted-firmware-a/v2.6+git-r0/git'
Command Error: 'quilt --quiltrc /build/tmp/work/old_silicon-poky-linux/trusted-firmware-a/v2.6+git-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/etc/quiltrc push' exited with 0  Output:
Applying patch 0002-trusted-firmware-a-add-rd-wr-64-bit-reg-workaround.patch
can't find file to patch at input line 5
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was: No file to patch.  Skipping patch.
6 out of 6 hunks ignored
patch unexpectedly ends in middle of line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added the patch properly (otherwise bitbake would've complained that the patch didnt exist), I'd still recommend you switch to the append syntax to avoid errors:

```
SRC_URI_append_old_sillicon = " file://0002-trusted-firmware-a-add-rd-wr-64-bit-reg-workaround.patch"
```

Your error is that your patch is being applied, however when `quilt` is applying your patch it can't find the file that its supposed to be modified (presumably gicv3_private.h).

Typically the file does exist and youre just trying to apply it in the wrong directory or something, hence why bitbake is suggesting to use the -p or --strip options for quilt, this would be the case if for example:

The patch is trying to modify

```
drivers/arm/gic/v3/gicv3_private.h
```

but the file is actually at

```
src/drivers/arm/gic/v3/gicv3_private.h
```

(or something similar)

Take a look at **striplevel** and **patchdir** in [SRC_URI](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html#term-SRC_URI), setting these properly is probably what you want.

Comment: This issue has been resolved but same problem is created in another file flash-writer.bbappend                                                                                                                          SRC_URI_old_silicon += "file://flash_writer_file_name.patch"
SRC_URI_new_silicon += "file://flash_writer_file_name.patch"  If I want to add patch in both of these machines errors are coming. any of the machine is not having this patch.                           ERROR: An uncaught exception occurred in runqueue

Comment: There should be no reason why that is happening, again I suggest you switch to the SRC_URI_append_old_sillicon = " file://your.patch" syntax.

And check how SRC_URI is constructed chronologically via:
`bitbake <your-recipe> -e | grep SRC_URI`

This will show you  how SRC_URI is defined first, then how certain parts of it are appended, and what is its final definition

Comment: bitbake flash-writer -e | grep SRC_URI

# $SRC_URI_old_silicon
SRC_URI_old_silicon="  file://flash_writer_file_name.patch"
So I copied same line in my .bbappend but still facing errors related to python checksum.py file

Comment: That sounds like a different error, what does it actually say about a checksum.py file?